# How to anchor a Button on a View in the center

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to accomplish the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5udT0.png)

The gray part is the background of the activity and the white part is a horizontal LinearLayout. I want to create the spinner overlapping the top border of the LinearLayout but everything I can do is put it inside the layout or on top of it. Is there a way to accomplish this? or a workaround?

Comment: use constraint layout to design this type of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ConstraintLayout` for this. We need to use combinations of two properties

```
layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf
layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf
```

This will center the `Button` or any other `View`

**Example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/topView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView" // this 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/topView" // and this is important, it aligns the view to the top view
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**:

[image]